# issue with post with string containg & in c#

Tags: c#, webclient

i am trying to make a post to url which should look like below image in body of fiddler.

correct post from fiddler

[image]

ISSUE HAPPENING : when i post it spilt from & (ampersand) and create separate entries for key value in body of fiddler.

my post in fiddler

[image]

what should i do to appear in single key value pair?

i am trying to post following data :

```
responseData = "paymentid=100131806470125606&amp;result=NOT+CAPTURED&amp;auth=138601&amp;ref=806420053674&amp;tranid=131806429899386&amp;postdate=0305&amp;trackid=100001182618838&amp;udf1=1&amp;udf2=2&amp;udf3=3&amp;udf4=4&amp;udf5=5&amp;amt=5190.0&amp;authRespCode=51"


        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString("https://example.com/test.php", "authRespCode=1&responseData = " + responseData);
        }
```

Comment: What you should do is post a [mcve] since we cannot guess how your code looks like

Comment: No, you have to [edit] your question. Comments are not for code

Comment: i have edited question added static string which i am posting using webclient.

Comment: i have solved it .. posted answer below thanks guys for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`:

```
var res = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseData);
```

then you can access you parameters like so:

```
res["paymentid"]
```

etc...

Comment: i need to send above string in body not in querystring.

Comment: It doesn't matter - that method parses a string. Maybe go and try it and undersytand more. Maybe even go into debug mode!?

Comment: The question looks entirely different to what it was five minutes ago...!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape your URI string:

```
string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString("https://example.com/test.php", "authRespCode=1&responseData = " + Uri.EscapeUriString(responseData));
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this line solved my problem :

```
responseData = responseData.Replace("&amp;", "&");
responseData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(responseData);
```

Complete code :

```
string responseData = Utilitycl.GetHtmlInputValue(getString, "responseData", Utilitycl.ELEMENTTYPE.INPUT);
responseData = responseData.Replace("&amp;", "&");
responseData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(responseData);
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString("https://example.com/test.php", "authRespCode=1&responseData = " + responseData);
}
```